# Group bindings to avoid code repetitionn

Tags: knockout.js

Is it possible to group bindings?

e.g. Both `enable` and `css` bindings refer to the same condition causing repetition.

```
<div data-bind="enable: errors().length == 0, css: { green: errors().length == 0 }">
```

and

e.g. A binding on multiple elements refers to the same condition.

```
<div data-bind="css: { green: errors().length == 0 }">
<div data-bind="css: { blue: errors().length == 0 }">
<div data-bind="css: { red: errors().length == 0 }">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `ko.computed` ([documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)) to hold the condition logic:

```
this.noErrors = ko.computed(function(){
    return this.errors().length == 0;
}, this);
```

Then you can simplify your bindings to:

```
<div data-bind="enable: noErrors, css: { green: noErrors }">
```

and

```
<div data-bind="css: { green: noErrors }">
<div data-bind="css: { blue: noErrors }">
<div data-bind="css: { red: noErrors }">
```

Or you can create your own [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) or you can use the new preprocessing feature to [extend Knockout's binding syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html) to encapsulate your custom "grouping" logic.